# Is Spring Integration suitable for web-farm processing of "reliable queue"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Sorry if title is confusing, let me explain my question.

Our team need to develop web service which is suppose to run on several `nodes` (web farm - horizontal scaling). We know how to implement this "manually", but we're pretty excited about `Spring Integration` which is new to us - so we really trying to understand whether this is good fit for our scenario - and if so we'll try to make use of it.

Typical scenario:

1. Sevaral servers ("`nodes`") running same web application (lets call it "`OurWebService`")
2. We need to pull files from external systems ("`InboundExtSystems`")
3. Process this data with help of other external systems (involves local resource-consuming operations) ("`UtilityExtServices`")
4. Submit processing results to another set of external systems ("`OutboundExtSystems`")

Non-functional requirements:

5. Due to performance reasons we cannot query `UtilityExtServices` by demand -AND- local processing also CPU-intensive. So we need to have queue, in order to control pace at which we performing requests and process results
6. We expect several nodes will equally pull tasks from this queue and process them
7. We need to make sure that every queued task pulled from `InboundExtSystems` will be handled - we need to guarantee that none of them will disappear.
8. We need to make sure timeouts are handled as well. If task processing timed out - we need to "`requeue`" this task (and make sure previous handled will not submit results for this task)
9. We need to be able to perform rolling updates. Like let's say 5 nodes are processing queue. We want to be able to sequentially stop-upgrade-start each node without noticeably impacting system performance.

**So question is**: is `spring integration` perfect fit for such case?

If answer is "Yes", could you kindly name primary components we should use primarily?

p.s. Sure enough we would probably also need to pick something as a message bus and queue acessible by every node (maybe redis, hazelcast or maybe rabbitmq, not sure what is more appropriate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a good fit. I would suggest rabbitmq for the transport/queuing and the [Spring Integration AMQP enpoints](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html).

Rolling updates shouldn't be an issue unless you change the format of the messages sent between nodes). But even then you could handle it relatively easily by moving to a new set of queues.

Comment: Gary, thank you for your answer, sure enough I can rely on Lead developer of Spring Integration opinion :-) Can you kindly suggest any articles closely related to what we need?

Comment: I am not aware of any specific articles for your use case but we're here to help if you get stuck.